# What is the exact word for a vehicle usage statistics?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

I was wondering what is the exact word of a vehicle usage statistics?
For example, what should I call my car's total traversed distance?

Comment: What other usage statistics did you have in mind?

Comment: There isn't an "exact" word.  "Mileage", for instance, may be used to mean several different things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The total of traversed kilometers is called the *mileage* of the car.

The liters of fuel used per 100 km can be called *(fuel) consumption* or *fuel economy*.

The height, width and length are the *dimensions* of the car.

I'm not aware of other specific words, but horsepower, weight, etc. all fall under the *(technical) specifications* of the car.

Comment: But, in the US, as least, "mileage" is also used to mean "miles per gallon".

Answer (score 1):

It's not a single word but you're talking about the odometer reading.

Answer (score 0):

*CARFAX* is a vendor that provides ***vehicle history reports***, and sometimes the vendor's name becomes a synonym for its product.

The report includes information about *mileage*, *maintenance*, *accidents*, *repairs*, and *ownership*.